# I want to create a wave background for menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, bootstrap-4

Bascially I want to create menu background on hover like a wave.
Here you can see the first one:

[image]

I need the same.
Can anyone let me know how I can do this?

```
<ul>
<li>likkebamser</li>
<li>Heldige Lakridser</li>
<li>Lakridser</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please make sure you add a minimal, complete and reproducible example, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try a search on wave background svg - lots of images and ways of making wave images.

Comment: You can do it with SVG, but you cannot use `<ul>` / `<li>` tags inside SVG

Answer (score -2):

On hover, you can use `background-color` and [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) (css) and use a custom path.

[This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157568/create-clip-path-wave-css-edges) can help you to do that.

An other solution is to use a custom image as background when an element of your menu have the hover. (With `background-size: cover;`)