# How to blend the div in css?

Tags: html, css

I have blended the rectangle using figma but I am searching for how to do it in css so it can view like below image (the blue one),

[image]

How to achive this is css ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0%;
            padding: 0%;
        }
        .outer {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .outer .inner {
            /*How to do blend it*/
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #12B1F2;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+curve+blend+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What you tried, show here

Comment: Thanks for you responce, I have added the some code :)

Comment: I am interested in the solution. An old CSS style way could maybe be to have two circles and work with two divs and the backgrounds vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `clip-path`.

There are two ways to do it:

- Create an SVG that has a path of the shape you want and use that as the clip-path: https://codesandbox.io/s/bezier-curve-clip-path-h8x8l?from-embed=&file=/index.html
- Generate a polygon yourself with code which approximates the curve you want. Have a look at this question here: [Create clip-path wave css edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157568/create-clip-path-wave-css-edges)