# How can i make smooth div corners in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make rounded corners for a div like [image]

I tried make it with clip-paths but when i make it its being so sharp. Not smooth as that one. How can i make it ? Thanks for responses!

My clip-path : `clip-path: polygon(23% 0, 99% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 4% 84%, 5% 63%, 9% 47%, 6% 28%, 14% 16%);`

[image]

As you can see its not smooth as in example. What can i do for solve it ? Thanks all!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157568/create-clip-path-wave-css-edges) help?

Comment: @RobMoll yes brother! Thank you! I searched before ask it but i didnt saw that topic. Thanks for help.!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create clip-path wave css edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157568/create-clip-path-wave-css-edges)